# How to send and receive SMS remotely (thru HTTP server)?

Tags: sms, remote-access, call-history

I would like to

- send SMS
- receive SMS
- get log of incoming calls (phone number, date & time)
- drop the incoming call

with some app installed on my old Android phone. Can I do it? Ideally, I think it should be some app with HTTP server running, so with usage of app's API I will be able to do all these actions. Does such app exist?

Comment: @Psychozoic, I haven't found any ready-for-use solution, but you can write your own solution with twilio api usage, for ex.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this what you are looking for?

1. [MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client)
2. [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)

Comment: No, since both apps require their application to be installed on PC, when I am looking for HTTP (API) access. SMS Gateway (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway&hl=en) is more close to what I need, but  calls are not supported.

Comment: Not AirDroid ... It's only browser